# Specifying filenames for ant junit batchtest

Tags: ant, junit

I have a working ant-task that runs me a batch of junit-tests, in the following fashion:

```
<junit printsummary="yes" showoutput="yes" haltonfailure="no">
    <formatter type="plain" />
    <classpath>
        <path refid="app.compile.classpath" />
        <path id="classes" location="${app.classes.home}" />
        <path id="test-classes" location="${app.build.home}/test-classes" />
    </classpath>
    <batchtest fork="no" todir="${app.tests.reports}">
        <fileset dir="${app.tests.home}">
            <include name="**/*Test*.java" />
        </fileset>
    </batchtest>
</junit>
```

Now this works fine right now, except for the names of the Test-reports that are generated. These names are overly long and follow the pattern:

```
TEST-com.company.package.Class.txt
```

**Is there a way for specify a file-naming pattern for the report files for batchtest, preferrably for ant 1.6.5?**

I know that for a single test, you can specify a filename by using the `outfile` attribute. In the [junit-task reference](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html), it's just stated that:

> It then generates a test class name for each resource that ends in `.java` or `.class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

According to the source code

```
protected void execute(JUnitTest arg, int thread) throws BuildException {
    validateTestName(arg.getName());

    JUnitTest test = (JUnitTest) arg.clone();
    test.setThread(thread);

    // set the default values if not specified
    //@todo should be moved to the test class instead.
    if (test.getTodir() == null) {
        test.setTodir(getProject().resolveFile("."));
    }

    if (test.getOutfile() == null) {
        test.setOutfile("TEST-" + test.getName());
    }

    // execute the test and get the return code
    TestResultHolder result = null;
    if (!test.getFork()) {
        result = executeInVM(test);
    } else {
        ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = createWatchdog();
        result = executeAsForked(test, watchdog, null);
        // null watchdog means no timeout, you'd better not check with null
    }
    actOnTestResult(result, test, "Test " + test.getName());
}
```

it will create the out file as `"TEST-"  + test.getName()` if you don't specify it explicitly in the `test` element. It's not possible to specify it in `batchtest` element.